# access an array in a nested reactive form group, linting error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a method to delete rows from my dynamic form and I am having trouble targeting the array.

so the form group is this:

```
this.piForm = this.fb.group({
    milestoneSaveModel: this.fb.group({
        milestonesToCreate: this.fb.array([this.mileStoneCreate()]),
    }),
});
```

and then my delete method is this so far:

```
deleteRow(index: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.piForm.controls['milestoneSaveModel'].controls['milestonesToCreate'];
    control.removeAt(index);
}
```

my linter tells me `Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.`

however when I trigger this in the browser it actually works. So how do i fix the linting error?

Comment: Try with `this.piForm.get('milestoneSaveModel').get('milestonesToCreate')` and tell me how it goes.

Comment: yep that worked like a charm!

Comment: I made an answer, feel free to mark your issue as resolved once you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this syntax instead :

```
this.piForm.get('milestoneSaveModel').get('milestonesToCreate')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert type of control to FormArray.

```
form.get('milestoneSaveModel').get('milestonesToCreate') as FormArray;
```